# Need user's email addresses from Azure Active Directory Domain Services

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm using [Azure Active Directory Domain Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-ds/) (AADDS) and need user's reachable email address information from it [via LDAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap) (typically with `mail` attribute, but other attributes would also work) to give user identities to some classic web services.  How can I set each user's email address in the Azure AD tenant which backs the AADDS?

I can see some email address settings in each AD user's profile in the Azure Portal, but none of them appear in the AADDS synced with the Azure AD.